# How do I filter with dropdown list? PHP and SQL

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

We are trying to filter based on the tags or the dropdown menu, we are trying to create a blog website that has tags and those tags can be used to filter the posted content on the homepage [Tags dropdown menu:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbZCJ.png).  Here should be the content in the page: [Here should be the content in the page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0qrf.jpg)

```
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="">Tags<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
          <ul class = "dropdown">
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">All</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">Homemade</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">Pro</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">Resto</button></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

```
<!-- Posting -->
 <div>
                <?php 
                  
                  $query = "select * from posts order by date limit 8";

                  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query,$tagHomemade);
                ?>
                
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0):?>
                  
                  <div>
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
                      
                      <?php 
                        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                        $query = "select username, image from users where id ='$user_id' limit 1";
                        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                        $user_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
                      ?>

                      <div class="card">
                        <div style ="display: flex;">
                          <div style ="flex:1", >
                            <div class="profile"><img class ="icon" src="<?=$user_row['image']?>"></div>
                          </div>

                          <div style ="flex:2;" >
                            <h5>Posted by: <?php echo $_SESSION['logged']['username']?>,
                              <?php echo date("jS M, Y",strtotime($row['date']))?>
                            </h5>
                            <h3><?php echo $row['tag']?>: <?php echo $row['title']?></h>
                          </div>  
                        </div>


                        <div>
                          <?php if (file_exists($row['image']))?>

                          <div class="img" style="text-align:center;">
                              <img class="postPic" src="<?=$row['image']?>">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                          <?php if (!empty ($POST['post']));?>
                          <?php echo $row['post']?>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif;?>`
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set tags in the url like this:

```
<li><a href="Home_loggedin.php?tag=homemade">Homemade</button></a></li>
```

Then you can get it by `$_GET['tag']` in your code. Then put it on the SQL query.

Good to know: It's strongly recommended to use prepared statements and don't use `$_GET['tag']` directly in your SQL code. It prevents SQL injection and cares about special characters as well.

Update:

```
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="">Tags<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
          <ul class = "dropdown">
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php">All</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php?tag=handmade">Homemade</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php?tag=pro">Pro</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Home_loggedin.php?tag=resto">Resto</button></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li> 
<!-- Posting -->
 <div>
                <?php 
                  $where = !empty($_GET['tag']) ? "where tag = '" . $_GET['tag'] . "'" : "";

                  $query = "select * from posts $where order by date limit 8";

                  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                ?>
                
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0):?>
                  
                  <div>
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
                      
                      <?php 
                        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                        $query = "select username, image from users where id ='$user_id' limit 1";
                        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                        $user_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
                      ?>

                      <div class="card">
                        <div style ="display: flex;">
                          <div style ="flex:1", >
                            <div class="profile"><img class ="icon" src="<?=$user_row['image']?>"></div>
                          </div>

                          <div style ="flex:2;" >
                            <h5>Posted by: <?php echo $_SESSION['logged']['username']?>,
                              <?php echo date("jS M, Y",strtotime($row['date']))?>
                            </h5>
                            <h3><?php echo $row['tag']?>: <?php echo $row['title']?></h>
                          </div>  
                        </div>


                        <div>
                          <?php if (file_exists($row['image']))?>

                          <div class="img" style="text-align:center;">
                              <img class="postPic" src="<?=$row['image']?>">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                          <?php if (!empty ($POST['post']));?>
                          <?php echo $row['post']?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif;?>
        </div>
```

Comment: So how do I do the prepared statements instead? Also, how do I implement the $_GET['tag']? will it filter the content based on if it is Homemade etc.?

Comment: This is the simple guide on how to use prepared statements in mysqli: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: `href="Home_loggedin.php?tag=homemade"` prepares `$_GET['tag']` for you. Just use it on your code like this: `$tag = $_GET['tag'];` then put it on your sql query to get posts

Comment: I updated the code to have a sample. I did not test it but I guess it works. Just care about prepared statements.

Comment: There seems to be an error,  I don't think it recognizes the tags that it's getting from the SQL, here is the error
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'Pro' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICS2608\Home_loggedin.php:124 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ICS2608\Home_loggedin.php(124): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'select * from p...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICS2608\Home_loggedin.php on line 124

Comment: line 124:  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

The problem probably occurred here:
 $where = !empty($_GET['tag']) ? "where tag = " . $_GET['tag'] : "";
   $query = "select * from posts $where  order by date limit 8";

Comment: It's just semi-code. For example, I have no idea about your columns in the post table. Is there any `tag` column there?

Comment: I updated the `$where = !empty($_GET['tag']) ? "where tag = " . $_GET['tag'] : "";` line to handle the string in the query (in a not secure way!)

Comment: yea there is a "tag" column in there, I don't really now why it wont handle the string query , this is currently what's in the SQL table: https://imgur.com/a/cy7ZqGv

Comment: Did you test the new code I've updated some minutes ago?

Comment: ohh, thank you, some of the elements are messed up but I can fix this on my own, mostly CSS problems but yes it did work